# Does Excel have an equivalent of SQL aggregate functions?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a table of data in it. The columns are "Item", "Price", "Owned". I want to sum the price of the owned items. In SQL, I would simply do

```
select sum(price) from table where owned="y"
```

Is there a formula I can use to do something similar in Excel? The DSUM function seems to do something like what I want, but I can't understand how the criteria work.

More generally, this is a problem I encounter a lot. I use SQL for a lot of data analysis, and use aggregate functions frequently. And yet, if I have my data in a spreadsheet rather than in a database table, I find it extremely difficult to do this type of analysis (without needing to clutter my spreadsheet with masses of working areas). Basically, I need to be able to take the sum/count/max/min/etc of a column, only including rows satisfying a particular condition, without needing a work column for each condition (it's easy enough with a work column, just have a column containing IF(condition,column,0) and then sum/count/whatever it).

Thanks,
Paul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SUMIF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) or use [array formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx). I prefer the latter method myself. As an example, say you have the *Item*, *Price*, and *Owned* data in columns *A*, *B*, and *C*, respectively. Then your array formula would look something like `SUM(B:B*(C:C="y"))`. Enter it using *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* as you would for an array formula and you are good. Of course, you can use Excel's other aggregation functions with minor tweaks, too.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising. I can't quite get it to work at the moment, but I'll do some research on array functions (they are new to me...)

Comment: You definitely should. You can really make Excel dance with those once you get the hang of it.

Comment: OK, got it. I was including the header (using B:B as you put) but the header isn't a number so I got #VALUE. Just using the data cells works great!

Answer (score 0):

Filtering data and applying functions to the result is the closest thing I can think of.